# Can morphisms in a concrete category admit mappings that are not functions?

Tags: logic, category-theory, relations

**EDIT:** The original question appears to have been worded much too abstractly in terms of constant and coconstant morphisms to admit a precise answer (for details see history), the new question has been restated in a much more concrete form after receiving comments.

**Restated question**: Can morphisms in a concrete category admit mappings that are not functions?

It arose when dualizing a constant function $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal C$ into a dual morphism $F(f):F(Y)\longrightarrow F(X)$ in $\mathcal B^{op}$ under a contravariant dually equivalent functor $F:\mathcal C\longrightarrow \mathcal B^{op}$ with $\mathcal C \simeq \mathcal B^{op}$ (dually equivalent). $F(f)$ then should map a constant $c\in Y$ in such a way that $F(f)(c):F(Y)\longrightarrow F(X)$ outputs its entire codomain $F(X)$, which is at the same time both the image and the output of $F(f)(c)$. This appears to be a multifunction rather than a function.

For more concreteness, $\mathcal B^{op}$ can be taken as $Set^{op}$. A construction is given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category#Further_examples) on how to embed $Set^{op}$ into the category **Rel** of sets and relations. Both **Rel** and $Set^{op}$ are known to be concrete categories. Then the morphism $F(f)$ in $Set^{op}$  that is dual to a constant function $f$ in $\mathcal C$ can be a multifunction, because relations need not be functions. Some more specifics and references are given in my comments to this post.

Comment: You don't define anything here. You just write down $F(c)$  and the property of $F(c)$ which follows from the property of $c$. And that's correct. One calls this a coconstant morphism. (Why not nstant ...) Google gives plenty of material.

Comment: Thanks @HeinrichD. I left a follow up question in the original post.

Comment: How do you define an element of $F(C)$? Remember the definition of a category, the objects are no sets. Maybe you want to talk about generalized elements. But in any case, one generalized element is mapped exactly to one generalized element. This is what maps do.

Comment: @HeinrichD I think perhaps the deduction follows if we restrict $\mathcal C,B$ to concrete categories. Since they are concrete, their morphisms may not be partial, i.e. they must be defined for the entire source (domain). Now since $\mathcal B$ is an opposite of concrete category, its morphisms $F(f)$ are reversed, and therefore they map every $f(x)$ to the entire target (codomain) of $F(f)$. Does this appear correct or am I missing something?

Comment: You have not understood the concept of a category resp. a morphism.

Comment: @HeinrichD In nLab there is an article (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/multi-valued+function) dealing many-valued functions and further this one shows (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/span) that such functions can be treated as morphisms, at least in some categories. I am thus not entirely sure whether morphisms must only output a single point.

Comment: Remember that you are in an arbitrary category here! $C$ can be any category, and $B$ can be chosen to be $C^{op}$. You mistake morphisms with maps.

Comment: @HeinrichD thank you, I am just trying to begin to grasp category theory. Are there any easy and/or reasonable assumptions we can make so that in fact $F(c)$ should map a points to its entire codomain, given $c$ is constant in $\mathcal C$? One trivial example would obviously be when the codomain has one point (element), but perhaps there are others. Also, I should be talking only about constant $c$ and not any morphism $f$, since only then it seems plausible that an dual element is mapped to the entire codomain of $c$.

Comment: What notion of "point" are you using here?

Comment: I had no preferred notion of a point. If there is no canonical definition of a point/element, let's restrict ourselves to concrete categories.

Comment: You can represent it as a map between the *powersets* $P(Y)\to P(X)$ namely $B\mapsto f^{-1}(B)$. For a constant map $f\equiv c$, this will be something like the principal ultrafilter of element $c$.

Comment: In the sense of "global points", in the sense of morphisms $1\to X$, then it will be the case that $f:X\to Y$ will, by composition simply take that point to another point, and coconstant morphisms don't rule out that the resulting points may be distinct. (And if such a point were epimorphic, it would be an isomorphism.) For a concrete category, it should be obvious that the idea of mapping an element to every element in the codomain is nonsensical: the underlying morphisms of a concrete category are *functions*, and cannot map that way.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thanks for the comment. Perhaps the problem can be stated more concretely: **Rel**, the category of pairs $(X,f)$ as objects, with $X$ a set in **Set**, and binary relations as morphisms $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ consisting of *all* pairs $(x,f(x))$, i.e. $f\subset X\times Y$. Obviously this admits arrows where we may have two pairs $(x,y_1), (x,y_2)$ for one element $x\in X$ and two elements $y_1,y_2\in Y$. This is a mapping of one $x$ to two $y_1,y_2$. My reference is Mac Lane, CWM, 2nd ed (1998), p.26 and http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf (2004), Example 5.5(1), p.64.

Comment: A correction: in **Rel** the objects are actually $(X,\rho)$, where $\rho$ is a binary relation on set $X$. The morphisms are relation-preserving maps $f:(X,\rho)\longrightarrow (Y,\sigma)$ such that $x\rho x'$ implies $f(x)\sigma f(x')$.

Comment: Is there a question in this post?

Comment: @Hurkyl the question was in the titile, I pasted it into the body for emphasis.

Comment: A) If you come up with a new question, you should probably post a new question, not just edit an older post. B) The former version of $\mathbf{Rel}$ you describe is the more standard one; the latter I've never seen outside *Abstract and Concrete Categories*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the most recent version of the question, the answer is that it depends on what you mean by "concrete category". The most common usage of the term means, specifically, a category equipped with a faithful functor to $\mathbf{Set}$, so the answer would be no. If you've been reading *Abstract and Concrete* categories, what most folks now call "concrete categories" are what those authors refer to as "constructs."

There is also the more general notion of "concrete over $\mathcal D$," meaning it's a category equipped with a faithful functor into $\mathcal{D}$. In this case, sure, you could have a concrete category over $\mathbf{Rel}$, or over the trivial category (as with preorders), or whatever else. For instance, $\mathbf{Set}$ is concrete over $\mathbf{Rel}$ in this sense, or over $\mathbf{Eff}$.

Comment: This perhaps nails it. I must have been thinking about concrete over $Set^{op}$ or something similar. Maybe there is something funny about embedding $Set^{op}$ into $Rel$. Thanks for the input.